# JQuery Numeric Spinner Autorounding

Tags: javascript, jquery, spinner

I am looking for a numeric spinner that has a property for incremental value (.25, .5, .75), supports auto-rounding in case someone types in a value (or an change event), max and min ranges, and support for custom images would be great.

This is a sample/demo of the page with the controls I plan on using http://jsfiddle.net/NwHGw/. I plan on adding a spinner to the lunch input box. I'm fairly new to JQuery so if this is a matter of just tying together a few different techniques please let me know. The plugin that is being used in this sample is [jQuery Time Entry](http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html) by Keith Wood.

Thanks for your help

Update (12/6 9:22 PM EST):
I have made an update to the code http://jsfiddle.net/NwHGw/1/. I was wondering what everyone thought of this implentation. The box I'm having issues with is the 'Lunch' box. It was originally going to be an decimal (1, 1.5, 2.25, ect), but if I use the same plugin as the time controls then I can specify the input as HH:MM, set the type to 24H and limit the input to say 00:00 to 03:00 and keep the rest of the logic the same. I can then do the decimal conversion on the backend.